# Outputting part of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following saved into a variable called `fieldErrors`.

```
 Object { url_title="This URL title is being ... titles must be unique."}
```

How can I output just the text within the " "? (This URL title is being ... titles must be unique.)

Comment: `fieldErrors.url_title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object literal definition looks rather like that (what you've written is wrong):

```
obj = { url_title: "This URL title is being ... titles must be unique." } 
console.log(obj.url_title) <- outputting
```

Comment: Ah so simple! Thank you.